# What permissions do I need to run a shell command programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, exec, android-permissions

```
         try{
             Process process;
             process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the command you wish to run, you may not need any.  However, if your attempting to run a system level command you will need root access (not an Android permission).  Running a platform command pretty much circumvents anything going on with Android permissions and is only affected by whether or not your linux user id has read/write/execute permission for the command you are issuing.

`Runtime.exec()` will also throw a `SecurityException` if you are not allowed to run a specific command and the exception will provide more details as to why in the specific case, so you should probably catch that in your `try` block also.  You may also use `Runtime.checkexec()` to verify if you can run a certain command string before you actually attempt it.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: It’s unlikely in this case, but could there be a per-app process limit?

Comment: A good rule of thumb would be, if you can log in to the device with `adb shell` and run the command you're interested in, your application should also be able to run it.  If you are distributing this application, don't expect users to have rooted their devices just so they can run your app ;)

Comment: you are right Wireless, I am trying to run push command through this code but getting following exception  :java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: Working Directory: null Environment: null ....04-06 12:37:43.234: WARN/System.err(367): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
I am not able to find a solution yet..:(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that no permissions are necessary here. But you can analyze the result of execution in order to understand were the binary get executed.